# Connecting google closure drag and drop file selector to Blobstore image uploader

Tags: google-app-engine, google-closure

I have a javascript frontend connect to a Google App Engine backend. The [instructions for uploading a file to Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview) assume you are using JSPs, which I am not. The [example for creating a file drop handler](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/demos/filedrophandler.html) assume you just want to send the file up by itself in a post.

This works for sending the file up:

```
var files = event.getBrowserEvent().dataTransfer.files;
if (files.length > 0) {
  if (files.length > 1) {
    console.log('Too many files!');
  } else {
    var file = files[0];

    var xhr = new goog.net.XmlHttp();
    xhr.open('POST', '/imageUpload?gwt.codesvr=localhost:9997');
    xhr.send(file);
  }
}
```

But this is just sending the data directly to my servlet. I could add a form to my html but as far as I can tell [closure doesn't like setting inputs of type file](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_dom_forms.js.html).

Suggestions as to how I can upload my files to the Blobstore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469533/449161), I finally figured this out.

First off, make sure sessions are enabled in your appengine-web.xml: `<sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>`

I ended up writing two separate servlets, one that creates the upload URL and the second that handles the redirect after the image is written to the blobstore.

**Image upload URL servlet**

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse) throws IOException {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    Map<String, String> payload = new HashMap<String, String>();

    payload.put("url", blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/imageUpload"));

    LOGGER.info("Payload: " + GSON.toJson(payload));

    pResponse.setContentType("application/json");
    pResponse.getWriter().println(GSON.toJson(payload));
}
```

**Client side image upload requestor**

```
// request function
...
goog.net.XhrIo.send('/imageUploadURL', goog.bind(this.handleURLReceived, this));
...

// response handler function
myapp.ImageDrop.prototype.handleURLReceived = function(event)
{
  this.postURL = this.extractValidJson(event).url;
  myapp.logger.fine('Response: ' + this.postURL);
};
```

`extractValidJson(event)` is just a utility function I wrote to pull out the json response.

Once we have a valid URL, we can allow uploads.

**Client side upload drop sender**

```
// In constructor
...
var dropZone = goog.dom.getElement('image-drop');
var handler = new goog.events.FileDropHandler(dropZone, true);
goog.events.listen(handler, goog.events.FileDropHandler.EventType.DROP, goog.bind(this.handleDrop, this));
...

// FileDropHandler
myapp.ImageDrop.prototype.handleDrop = function(event)
{
  var files = event.getBrowserEvent().dataTransfer.files;

  var file = files[0]; // IRL, do error checking

  this.xhr = new goog.net.XmlHttp();
  this.xhr.open('POST', this.postURL, true); // asych
  this.xhr.onreadystatechange = goog.bind(this.uploadResponseHandler, this);

  var form_data = new FormData();
  form_data.append('file', file); // name is arbitrary, must match in servlet      
  this.xhr.send(form_data);
};
```

**Image upload redirect servlet**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse) throws IOException {
    Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(pRequest);

    // 'file' matches param name from form
    for (BlobKey key : blobs.get("file")) {
        LOGGER.info("We have a KEY!!!! " + key);
        blobstoreService.delete(key); // Just testing
    }

    // Make this a real response        
    pResponse.setContentType("text/html");
    pResponse.getWriter().println("OK");
```

}

Then you can do whatever in your uploadResponseHandler. Request finished is 4 ([see this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp)).

```
myapp.ImageDrop.prototype.uploadResponseHandler = function(event)
{ 
  if (this.xhr.readyState === myapp.ImageDrop.REQUEST_FINISHED) {
    myapp.logger.fine('Request finished!');
  }
};
```

Not so bad once all the pieces come together.