# Add a File (JS object) to input type="file"

Tags: javascript, file, fileapi, html-input

I need a way to add a File object to a file input field.

Note that **I do not want to [set the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)** of the file field. (which is a security risk, ... I know that)
I already **have the file** itself (and all its contents!)

I'm creating the File object like this:

```
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var file = new File([blob], 'file.png');
  // and now I want to add MY File to the input here
});
```

Please don't tell me about how to upload the File, I know about XMLHttpRequest Level 2. I want to upload the File to an external website (potentially using a userscript or something similar).

So, how can I achieve that?
Or if it's not possible: why can't I add a File that I actually own (because I created it in the Browser (as a virtual File, which does not even exist in the users filesystem)) to an input field that I own too? (technically the input field could be my own, that does not matter here)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html file input, set selection from File object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469479/html-file-input-set-selection-from-file-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible:

To load file from blob:

```
  let fileInputElement = document.getElementById('file_input');
  let container = new DataTransfer();
  // Here load or generate data
    let data = new Blob();
    let file = new File([data], "g"+i+".jpg",{type:"image/jpeg", lastModified:new Date().getTime()});
    container.items.add(file);
  fileInputElement.files = container.files;
```

To load file from another file input:

```
  let input1 = document.getElementById('file_input');
  let input2 = document.getElementById('some_other_input')
  let container = new DataTransfer();
   [...input2.files].map(file=>container.items.add(file));
  input1.files = container.files;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Kartearis/gmhwnaz6/3/

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469479/html-file-input-set-selection-from-file-object):

> It seems like you want to take the File object from the drop event and assign it to the  element. Unfortunately, you can't do that. Only the user can select files; you can't dynamically change the files which will be uploaded because browsers deny JavaScript this ability for security reasons.

Comment: yes...because if it is allowed to programatically change the `input file`, the web-developer can easily steal user's files..

Comment: yes, it is possible, see accepted answer below